# What is wrong with my proof that $f^{-1}(S)$ is open?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces, epsilon-delta

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces, $f: X \to Y$ is continuous, $S \subset Y$, and $S$ open. Prove that $f^{-1}(S)$ is open, where $f^{-1}(S) = \{x \in X : f(x) \in S\}$.

If $x \in f^{-1}(S)$, then $f(x) \in S$ and since $S$ is open, there exists a $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $y \in X$, $d(f(x), f(y)) < \epsilon$, $f(y) \in S$. Since $f$ is continuous, we can find a $\delta > 0$ such that $d(x, y) < \delta$ implies $d(f(x), f(y)) < \epsilon$. Thus $d(x, y) < \delta$ implies that $f(y) \in S$, so $y \in f^{-1}(S)$. Therefore $f^{-1}(S)$ is open.

This was marked incorrect on my exam, and now that I read over it, I'm not sure it makes any sense. I think I am having trouble integrating the concept of openness with the definition of continuity, because an open ball is a set of elements and continuity is just comparing different elements using metrics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marked incorrect? Doesn't make any sense?  I think you got the spirit of the proof down.  Did you not receive *any* points?  If so, I would defend my answer to the professor.  My proof is as follows:

Let $x \in f^{-1}(S)$.  We want to find some $\delta > 0$ such that $B(x, \delta) \subseteq f^{-1}(S)$, and this will show $f^{-1}(S)$ is open.

But $x \in f^{-1}(S)$ implies $f(x) \in S$.  Since $f(x)$ is in $S$ and $S$ is open, there is some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B(f(x), \epsilon) \subseteq S$.  But since $f$ is continuous, we know there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $f(B(x, \delta)) \subseteq B(f(x), \epsilon)$.  But since $B(f(x), \epsilon) \subseteq S$, this implies $B(x, \delta) \subseteq f^{-1}(S)$.  Thus, we found a $\delta > 0$ such that $B(x, \delta) \subseteq f^{-1}(S)$, and since $x$ was arbitrary, this shows $f^{-1}(S)$ is open.

As you can see, it's **very** similar in idea to yours.

Comment: The professor doesn't give any partial credit. He says anyone can get the general idea of a concept, but when it comes to solutions, you either know it or you don't

Comment: @ᴇʏᴇs I disagree with him.  Plenty of people have trouble getting the general idea of a proof (I think that's the biggest hurdle for undergrad students in math to overcome regarding proofs).  Sure, you need to work on how you formally write a proof to clean up some statements and be absolutely clear about your steps.  But the hardest and most important part about proof writing is seeing a problem and getting a feeling of how to solve it.  You did just that.  I would have given you at least half credit.

Comment: I understand that continuity implies there exists a $\delta$ such that $d(x,a) < \delta \implies d(f(x), f(a)) < \epsilon$, but I don't get how $f(B(x, \delta)) \subseteq B(f(x), \epsilon)$ follows from continuity

Comment: @ᴇʏᴇs What does it mean for $d(x,a) < \delta$?  It means $a$ is within $\delta$-distance of $x$, i.e., $a \in B(x, \delta)$.  With continuity, we are saying for all $a$ within $\delta$-distance of $x$, i.e., for all $a \in B(x, \delta)$, we get that $f(a)$ is within $\epsilon$-distance of $f(x)$, i.e., $f(a) \in B(f(x), \epsilon)$.  So we have that for all $a \in B(x,\delta)$, $f(a) \in B(f(x), \epsilon)$.  This means the image of $B(x,\delta)$ is contained in $B(f(x), \epsilon)$, i.e., $f(B(x,\delta)) \subseteq B(f(x), \epsilon)$.

Answer (score 3):

This sentence:

> since $S$ is open, there exists a $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $y \in X$, $d(f(x),f(y))<\epsilon$, $f(y) \in S$

doesn't make sense (what is "$f(y) \in S$" stand for, a conclusion or a condition on $y$?) and makes statements about $f$ while claiming the justification is the openness of $S$, so it's certainly not true without a condition on $f$ and you would need to prove this fact from that condition.

**Edit:** On second thought, I think there is a way to interpret that sentence such that it's correct and your proof is correct.  What I will say though is that as a teacher I probably still wouldn't give you points back.  Remember that the point of writing proofs is to communicate mathematics to others.  If you write in a way that can be easily misinterpreted as wrong then you aren't communicating correctly.  In the future you should make sure you write out your "such that's" instead of using commas and make sure you use definitions (like the openness of $S$) directly, instead of skipping straight to a consequence of that definition (which is what, upon reflection, I think you're doing).

Answer (score 2):

Since $S$ is open, there is $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(f(x),\epsilon)\subset S$ or if $y$ such that $d_Y(f(x),y)<\epsilon$, then $y\in S$. Then by $\epsilon-\delta$ continuity, there is a $\delta$ such that $d_X(x,z)<\delta$, then $d_Y(f(x),f(z))<\epsilon\Rightarrow f(z)\in S\Rightarrow z\in f^{-1}(S)$. Thus, if $d_X(x,z)<\delta$, $z\in f^{-1}(S)$, so $B(x,\delta)\subset f^{-1}(S)$. So $S$ is open.

I don't think you're flat out wrong, but there are a few mistakes in there. Actually, as an edit: I don't think it's entirely fair to mark this incorrect, especially for what is presumably an undergraduate course in analysis using Rudin (based on your tags). Maybe points off, but not incorrect.But what can you do.

Comment: How do you know that $x \in f^{-1} (S)$?

Comment: You assume $f(x)\in S\Rightarrow x\in f^{-1}(S)$